# How to get XML via Jsoup with element im:image?

Tags: java, xml, jsoup

I have a XML link: http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=100/xml. I want get all content via Jsoup. But i have problem when i get content with XML element:

```
<im:image height="53">
http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/111/Purple/v4/3d/6a/2b/3d6a2b17-e46c-5609-1bdc-1a3935ed2e51/mzl.edqotirc.53x53-50.png
</im:image>
<im:image height="75">
http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/111/Purple/v4/3d/6a/2b/3d6a2b17-e46c-5609-1bdc-1a3935ed2e51/mzl.edqotirc.75x75-65.png
</im:image>
<im:image height="100">
http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/111/Purple/v4/3d/6a/2b/3d6a2b17-e46c-5609-1bdc-1a3935ed2e51/mzl.edqotirc.100x100-75.png
</im:image>
```

How to get value content in im:image? Thank!

Comment: 1) What have you tried? and 2) you say that you "have problem" but don't describe it. What kind of problems *specifically* are you having with your own code?

Comment: And what do you mean by "get all the content"?

Answer (score 1):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.select("im|image");
for (Element element: elements )
{
System.out.println(element.text());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Jsoup is a HTML parser, not XML.
Second: try seletor:

```
doc.select("im:image").text();
```